# getting null on fromJson after editing file using torsion

Tags: json

am writing fields of an object out like this:

```
    String jsonStr = Main.gson.toJson(myObject);
    UFile tempFile = getTempFile();
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(tempFile);
    file.write(jsonStr);
    file.close();
```

This writes out fine to a file.

```
    {“myObject”: [{
    "Status": 6,
    "name": “test”,
     “Type": 2
    }]}
```

but if I change a value in the file like such:

```
    {“myObject”: [{
     "Status": 1,
     "name": “test”,
     “Type": 2
     }]}
```

and then do

```
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(tempFile)
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f, "UTF-8");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
       text.append(scanner.nextLine());

    myObject mobj = Main.gson.fromJson(text.toString(), myObject.class);
```

the status value is null.

if I change it back to 6 it shows the status value as 6 fine when it is read in.

Why does changing a value in the file not allow the value to be read in?

Comment: "torsion" was supposed to be toJson. thanks spell checker.